# Join two dataframes in scala spark using full join

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have two dataframes

```
Dataframe1:
 "a","x"
  1 , 2
  3 , 4
  2 , 5

Dataframe2:
 "a","y"
  1 , 3
  3 , 5
  7 , 6
```

I want to create a new DataFrame which is something like this

```
"a", "x" , "y"
  1    2     3
  3    4     5
  2    5     null
  7    null  6
```

I tried using joins, but it creates two new columns of the joined key. How should I proceed?

Comment: Drop the extra column(s)? 

Comment: There is no extra column

Comment: `val fullJoined = df1.join(df2, Seq("a"), "outer")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use join and specify the column that you want to join based on ("a" column), Spark will automatically remove unnecessary column after join

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object test extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  val df1 = Seq((1, 2), (3, 4), (2, 5)).toDF("a", "x")
  val df2 = Seq((1, 3), (3, 5), (7, 6)).toDF("a", "y")

  val resultDF = df1.join(df2, Seq("a"), "outer")
  resultDF.show()
//  +---+----+----+
//  |  a|   x|   y|
//  +---+----+----+
//  |  1|   2|   3|
//  |  3|   4|   5|
//  |  7|null|   6|
//  |  2|   5|null|
//  +---+----+----+
```

This is the format of Join method

```
def join(right: Dataset[_], usingColumns: Seq[String], joinType: String): sql.DataFrame
```

Equi-join with another DataFrame **using the given columns**.

Different from other join functions, the **join columns will only appear once** in the output, i.e. similar to SQL's JOIN USING syntax.

Params:

right – Right side of the join operation.

**usingColumns** – Names of the columns to join on. This columns must exist on both sides.

joinType – Type of join to perform.